# How do I make the paddle move with the arrow keys?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to make it so that you can move the paddle (making a pong game) with the arrow keys. I already have most of the code but I'm confused as to what I would pass to the function that will move the paddle.

Here is my code (this was base code given to us by our instructor, we just modified parts of it):

```
import math
import random
import sys, pygame
from pygame.locals import *

import ball
import colors
import paddle

# draw the scene
def draw(screen, ball1, paddle1) :
   screen.fill((128, 128, 128))
   ball1.draw_ball(screen)
   paddle1.draw_paddle(screen)

#function to start up the main drawing
def main():

   pygame.init()
   width = 600
   height = 600
   screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))

   ball1 = ball.Ball(300, 1, 40, colors.RED)
   paddle1 = paddle.Paddle(100, 575, colors.BLUE, 100, 20)

   while 1:
      for event in pygame.event.get():
         if event.type == QUIT: sys.exit()
         elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
               paddle1.update_paddle()
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
               paddle1.update_paddle()

      draw(screen, ball1, paddle1)
      pygame.display.flip()

if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

In the while loop, where it says "paddle1.update_paddle()", I need to pass it some arguments to make the paddle move. But this is where I got confused. (I am just starting to learn python!)

Here is what the update_paddle function looks like:

```
 def update_paddle(self, dx):
      self.x += dx
```

So as you can see, update_paddle just increments the paddle's x position by an input value. But what I'm confused about is, what exactly would I put as the input value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can do something like:

```
def update_paddle(self, dir, dx):
    if dir=='left':
        self.x -= dx
    elif dir=='right':
        self.x += dx
```

Then you can simply do:

```
paddle1.update_paddle('left',5)
paddle2.update_paddle('right',3)
```

Comment: If I were to position the paddle on the bottom of the screen so that the ball drops from the ceiling, would the 'up' and 'down' just change to right and left respectively?

Comment: @Karen, Yep, I'll do that now.

Comment: Thank you! And one last question, does it matter what numbers I put as the second argument?

Comment: @Karen, No it doesn't. But remember, it affects how fast the paddle moves since dx is basically speed

Comment: @Karen, If my answer was helpful, would you mind accepting it? Thank you.